# Look for similar strings in a text file C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file that contains:

*Memory Test*

Test Results : Pass

*Video Test*

Test Results : Pass

*Audio Test*

Test Results : Fail

I need to return 'true' if all Test Results are Pass and 'false' if one or more test results is Fail.

```
List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt").ToList<string();
   //If all "Test results : Pass"
   {
       return true;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
   {
       if (filecontents[i].Contains("Test Results : Fail"))
       {                          
           return false;
       }
   }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `var isValid = filecontents.Any(line => (line.StartsWith("Test Results") && line.EndsWith("Fail"))`

Answer (score 4):

You already got it,

....

```
for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
{
   if (filecontents[i].Contains("Test Results : Fail"))
   {                          
       return false;
   }
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to read the entire file into memory at once:

```
var oneOrMoreTestsFailed = 
    File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Any(x => x.Contains("Test Results : Fail"));

return !oneOrMoreTestsFailed;
```

This reads the file line-by-line. It also will exit when it encounters the first failure. So it doesn't necessarily have to read the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are really just looking for the presence of "Fail" right?

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText("myText.txt");
    if (text.Contains("Fail"))
        return false;
```

Comment: What about "System Failure Test, Test Result: Pass" :-)?

Comment: @vojta I based my answer on what the OP posted as his sample text doc. If "System Failure Test" was a test case then the OP would just need to use .Contains("Test Results : Fail")